# When to contact the faculty after a postdoc interview

Tags: postdocs, recommendation-letter, interview

I recently had a postdoc interview in which the professor said would contact me by next week. Later on, I got an email from the professor saying recommendation letters would be requested from my references. However, one week passed, neither my references nor I have heard anything from the professor.
Should I contact the professor or just wait for a few more days? Anyone know why my references have not been contacted despite what the professor said?